# find $\varepsilon$ such that $P(X\geq a+\varepsilon \land X\leq b - \varepsilon)=0.95$, with $X$ is uniformly distributed.

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Sketching the situation using the density function of the uniform distribution on $[a,b]$
its clear to me that is just a $0.025$ of $V:=∫_Ω \mathbb 1_Ω(x)\ dx$ it can't be simply $\varepsilon:= a+b\cdot 0.025$ or can it? Since I'm unsure if this holds when $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$. Is the skech even correct?
[image: sketch]

Comment: I get $(b-a)\times 0.025$

Comment: I'm disappointed that you deleted your question about quantifiers in the pumping lemma, as I was about to post a detailed response.

Comment: [I put it here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22127/25554) in case you are still interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given probability is just $\frac {(b-\epsilon) -(a+\epsilon)} {b-a}$. Setting this equal to $0.95$ and solving for $\epsilon$ gives $\epsilon=(0.025) (b-a)$.